# Create from Existing MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

So i have my model and i want to create a new plant from an existing plant selected from a drop down list with the same properties as the old plant except the scientific name.I created a function that will take the new plant name and the old plant and creates a new plant with old properties.I want to know what should i do in my controller and view in order to create this new plant from existing.

Here is my model

```
public class ExistingPlant
{

    public string selectedPlant { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Guid,string> plantList { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult CreateFrom()
    {
        ExistingPlant existing = new ExistingPlant();

        Dictionary<Guid, string> plants = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();

        foreach(var item in context.Plants){

            plants.Add(item.PlantId , item.ScientificName);
             }

        existing.plantList = plants;
        existing.selectedPlant = "Value";

        var plant = context.Plants.Where(d => d.ScientificName == existing.selectedPlant);
        string temp = existing.selectedPlant;
        Plant p = (Plant) plant;
        CopyExisting(p,temp);

        return View(existing);
    }
```

and my view code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset id="field">
    <div>
        <label> Scientific Name:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.selectedPlant)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>m.selectedPlant)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.selectedPlant,
    new SelectList(Model.plantList, "Key", "Value")
)
```

}

Comment: The method you wrote, is it not giving what you wanted ? If not, what is missing ?

Comment: The method is CopyExisting.It works the problems i'm having is to create a new plant from the string entered in the view with the selected plant from the dropdownlist.I'm having a problem too in casting the variable into a plant since my function takes a plant not a variable

Comment: You need an additional property for the new name of the plant. And the code to copy the existing plant should be in the POST method, not the GET method.

Comment: how can i cast the var into plant? it's giving me an error

Comment: I will add an answer shortly

Comment: Hello , i edited my question.Please find my edited answer and try to help me!Thank you

Comment: @AbdallaIsmail (see how this message starts to notify a user who has commented). You cannot just completely change you question based on an answer (the current answers and comments hen make no sense and I have rolled back your changes). I have given you an answer which works so I'm not sure why your not following it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a property in your view model for the new name, and when you submit the form, get the selected plant, clone it, update the scientific name based on the view model and save it.

Change you view model to

```
public class CopyPlantVM
{
  [Display(Name = "Existing Plant")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an existing plant")]
  public Guid ExistingPlant { get; set; }
  public SelectList ExistingPlantList { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "New scientific name")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter new scientific name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the view to

```
@model CopyPlantVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ExistingPlant)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExistingPlant, Model.ExistingPlantList, "Please select")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ExistingPlant)

  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)

  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

and the controller methods to

```
public ActionResult CreateFrom()
{
  CopyPlantVM model = new CopyPlantVM();
  ConfigureViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateFrom(CopyPlantVM model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // Get the selected plant
  Plant existingPlant = db.Plants.Where(p => p.PlantID = model.ExistingPlant).FirstOrDefault();
  // Create a new plant based on existing plant but with new name
  Plant newPlant = new Plant
  {
    ScientificName = model.Name,
    // set other properties based on existing plant
  };
  db.Plants.Add(newPlant);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction(...);
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(CopyPlantVM model)
{
  model.ExistingPlantList = new SelectList(db.Plants, "PlantId", "ScientificName");
}
```